# How to compare two Oracle schemas to get delta changes by Altering the table not to drop and recreate it

Tags: oracle, schema, redgate

I've already tried out a tool named TOYS. I found it free but unfortunately it didn't work.

Then, I tried "RED-Gate Schema Compare for Oracle" but it uses the technique to drop and recreate the table mean while I need to just alter the table with the newly added/dropped columns.

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that neither TOAD nor SQL Developer Diff tools are not recommended due to License issue with the client.

Comment: The Red Gate tool is designed to alter a table wherever possible, so it's possible this is a bug. Please feel free to contact us oracle@red-gate.com or submit a support request here: http://redgatesupport.red-gate.com/anonymous_requests/new

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Oracle 11g you could use [dbms_metadata_diff](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_metadiff.htm#CHEGCGCB) package and specifically `compare_alter()` function to compare metadata of two schema objects:

```
 Schema #1 HR

 create table tb_test(
    col number
  )


 Schema #2 HR2

  create table tb_test(
    col_1 number
  )


 select dbms_metadata_diff.compare_alter( 'TABLE'    -- schema object type
                                        , 'TB_TEST'  -- object name
                                        , 'TB_TEST'  -- object name
                                        , 'HR'       -- by default current schema
                                        , 'HR2'
                                        ) as res
  from dual;
```

Result:

```
RES                                                                            
-------------------------------------------------
ALTER TABLE "HR"."TB_TEST" ADD ("COL_1" NUMBER);
ALTER TABLE "HR"."TB_TEST" DROP ("COL");
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but actually I don't need to specify the type of the object as mentioned above. if you've around 100 table , 100 procedures , views , grants ...etc I think it wouldn't be the appropriate query to use for each single object in the model. Is there another generic method.

Comment: @user1107736 First of all. Everything in your question is about tables, there is not a single word about other objects. Second. `dbms_metadata_diff.compare_alter()` allows you to compare *not only* objects of `table` object type. Third. You could write a simple stored procedure where by querying `dba_objects` data dictionary view you will get object names and their types and do comparison.

Comment: Thank you very much. could you kindly help with this error, i got this message when I tried to execute the query "The specified object was not found in the database." Although the table is exist in both. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1107736 It simply means that the object, name of which you are passing in as a parameter into the `dbms_metadata_diff.compare_alter` function, is not present in a schema.